# Determine the order relation between $x$ and $y$, given $5x-2y =2y-3x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gre-exam

Given: $5x-2y =2y-3x $
$$ \begin{aligned}
      \text{Quantity A} && \text{Quantity B} \\
        x             && y  
      \end{aligned}$$

$\bigcirc $ Quantity A is bigger

$\bigcirc $ Quantity B is bigger

$\bigcirc $ Two quantities are equal

$\bigcirc $ The relationship cannot be determined for the information given

The answer is $B$ according to GRE book. Simplifying I get that $2x=y$. I letting  $x=0$  get $y=0$. Also let $x=1$ get $y=2$. I believe it is D but need to double check. I have read that any number in GRE is real.

Comment: The answer is B according to book. simplifying get that $2x=y$. I letting  $x=0$  get $y=0$. Also let $x=1$ get $y=2$. I belief it is D but need to double check. I have read that any number in GRE is real.

Comment: B means "quantity B is bigger". D means "The relationship cannot be determined from the given information"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5x-2y=2y-3x$, so $8x=4y$, so $y=2x$. There are a few possibilities. For example, $x=1$ and $y=2$, or $x=-1$ and $y=-2$, or $x=y=0$. If all we know is that $x,y$ are real, then it is not possible to know which is bigger.

Comment: so is x or y bigger or  are they equal or neither. Still technically have not answer the question.

Comment: ... Therefore the answer is "Cannot be determined"

Comment: So, the relationship cannot be determined. and the Princeton review doesn't know the first thing about math. Thanks!!! Wonder if ets does the same thing.

Comment: @Hugo Books contain typos.

Comment: There getting paid to do this. It should be perfect.